# MVC4 Links Around Images - IE9

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, url

I've got something very odd going on with some image links I've built into an MVC4 application.

They are defined in a Razor view like this:

```
        <a href="@Url.Action("Register", "Account")">
            <img src="~/Images/register.png" alt="register-graphic" title="Register" />
        </a>
```

When I debug this the page loads and all three instances of image links defined as above are fine. Click any of the images and the browser navigates to the target.

Works flawlessly in Firefox, Chrome ... however, that beautifully crafter other browser utterly fails.

If I debug this in IE on first load all the links are fine, if i navigate to one of the pages it works, if I hit the home page link to go back to the original page all is fine as well.

However, if I click one of the links, visit that page and just hit the back button, all the links are killed, the only link that is still present on the images is the first link in the page and that seems to get a copy of ALL the pages HTML as the URL!!!!!

I've tried all the various rendering modes in IE and they all behave the same.

I have literally no idea what to even try to fix this.

As far as I can tell IE is just making web development even harder with every new release, I thought by 2013 IE would be sorted ... :(

Comment: Corrupted IE cache perhaps? Does it happen on more than one machine?

Comment: What version of IE is this happening on (IE6/7/8/9/10)? Do you have a test page we can see this behavior?

Comment: I've tried clearing the cache and that had no impact on the results. This is possibly the weirdest thing I've seen IE9 do ...

Comment: @Elijah I'm using IE9, have tried all the modes and this is still in dev so no pages I can link you to unfortunately.

Comment: This actually just gets weirder.  It appears that the a tags from the links entirely vanishes from the HTML ... !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer as of yet but having tested this on other machines the behaviour IS working as expected on other machines ... VERY odd